# Javascript to dynamically increase html textarea height upwards

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code which will increase the height of the textarea downwards, but how do I increase it upwards? I'd like to only use javascript and CSS

Javascript

```
function auto_grow(element) {
  element.style.height = "5px";
  element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight) + "px";
}
```

CSS

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea rows="1" oninput="auto_grow(this)"></textarea>
```

Comment: function auto_grow(element) {
  element.style.height = "5px";
  element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight) + "px";
  element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}

try this

Answer (score 1):

To do so, you'll have to create a div that appear on top of the textarea and copy the content from the textarea into that div.

Then you can get the div to auto-grow while typing in it as you have access to the height of the content in the div.

For a clear tutorial on how to achieve this, I would suggest to read and recreate what is shown in that Css-Tricks post: https://css-tricks.com/the-cleanest-trick-for-autogrowing-textareas/